# Eigen C++: Performance of sparse-matrix manipulations

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

Can anybody explain the following behavior of Eigen sparse matrices? I have been looking into [aliasing](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html) and [lazy evaluation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html), but I don't seem to be able to improve on the issue. Tech specs: I am using the latest Eigen stable release on Ubuntu 16.10 with g++ compiler and no optimization flags.

Suppose I define a simple identity in the following way:

```
SparseMatrix<double> spIdent(N,N);
spIdent.reserve(N);
spIdent.setIdentity();
```

then perform these operations with it

```
spIdent-spIdent;
spIdent*spIdent;
spIdent - spIdent*spIdent;
```

and measure the computation times for all three. What I get is this

```
0 Computation time: 2.6e-05
1 Computation time: 2e-06 
2 Computation time: 1.10706
```

Meaning that either operation is fast, but the combination is super slow. The `noalias()` method is only defined for *dense* matrices, plus in my dense example it did not make much of a difference. Any enlightenment?

MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "../Eigen/Sparse"

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main() {

unsigned int N=2000000;

SparseMatrix<double> spIdent(N,N);
spIdent.reserve(N);
spIdent.setIdentity();

clock_t start=clock();
spIdent*spIdent;
cout << "0 Computation time: " << float(clock() - start)/1e6 << '\n';

start=clock();
spIdent-spIdent;
cout << "1 Computation time: " << float(clock() - start)/1e6 << '\n';

start=clock();
spIdent - (spIdent*spIdent);
cout << "2 Computation time: " << float(clock() - start)/1e6 << '\n';

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Uh, use the optimization flags?

Comment: The issue is not exactly just about making it faster... But understanding why the third case is so slow!

Comment: The first two where probably optimized away to no code at all.  The third was not.

Comment: Asking about speed without optimization turned on, is an exercise in futility.

Comment: Try showing the assembler code in each of the 3 examples and you will be enlightened.

Comment: Can you create a MCVE code that reproduces your timing result? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you run them under `/usr/bin/time -v` ? You be running out of RAM (and swapping).

Comment: I think the problem in `spIdent - (spIdent*spIdent)` is that an _intermediate_ container is produced and the data is copied into that. That takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so much that it gets optimized out as much as the lazy evaluation is, well, very lazy. Look at the product. The code that's called is (at least in whatever version of Eigen that was included on this machine):

```
template<typename Derived>
template<typename OtherDerived>
inline const typename SparseSparseProductReturnType<Derived,OtherDerived>::Type
SparseMatrixBase<Derived>::operator*(const SparseMatrixBase<OtherDerived> &other) const
{
  return typename SparseSparseProductReturnType<Derived,OtherDerived>::Type(derived(), other.derived());
}
```

which returns an *expression* of the product (i.e. lazy). Nothing is done with this expression, so the cost is zero. The same goes for the difference. Now, when doing `a-a*a` the `a*a` is an expression. It then meets the `operator-`. This sees the expression on the right hand side. This expression is then evaluated to a temporary (i.e. costs time) in order to use it in `operator-`. Why evaluate to a temporary? Read [this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html) for their logic (search for "The second circumstance").

`operator-` is a `CwiseBinaryOp` with the product expression as the right hand side. The first thing `CwiseBinaryOp` does is assign the right hand side to a member:

```
EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE CwiseBinaryOp(const Lhs& aLhs, const Rhs& aRhs, const BinaryOp& func = BinaryOp())
      : m_lhs(aLhs), m_rhs(aRhs), m_functor(func)
```

(`m_rhs(aRhs)`) which in turn calls a `SparseMatrix` constructor:

```
/** Constructs a sparse matrix from the sparse expression \a other */
template<typename OtherDerived>
inline SparseMatrix(const SparseMatrixBase<OtherDerived>& other)
  : m_outerSize(0), m_innerSize(0), m_outerIndex(0), m_innerNonZeros(0)
{
  ...
  *this = other.derived();
}
```

which in turn calls `operator=` which will (somebody correct me if I'm wrong) always trigger an evaluation, in this case, to a temporary.

Comment: So, is it possible to avoid the temporary variable in the expression `a - a * a`?

Comment: Using the bottom up approach employed in Eigen 3.2, I don't think so. Eigen 3.3 (beta) *may* employ a top down approach (I think I remember seeing that somewhere, but I could be wrong). If you're asking is it theoretically possible, then sure.

Comment: To be more precise, in Eigen 3.2, the product in the third statement is immediately evaluated into a temporary. This is not the case anymore with Eigen 3.3. So with Eigen 3.3, all three statements boil down to no-op. However, even with 3.3, once the third statement is assigned to a given matrix, then the product will be evaluated within a temporary. Evaluating it lazily through dot product would be extremely slow. In this case, the temporary is worth it!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Well, as people mentioned, in the first two statements the code gets optimized away entirely (I have tested with a current version of g++ and `-O3` set). The disassembly shows this for the second statement:

```
  400e78:   e8 03 fe ff ff          callq  400c80 <clock@plt>   # timing begins
  400e7d:   48 89 c5                mov    %rax,%rbp
  400e80:   e8 fb fd ff ff          callq  400c80 <clock@plt>   # timing ends
```

Fop the third part there is actually something happening an Eigen library code is called:

```
  400ede:   e8 9d fd ff ff          callq  400c80 <clock@plt>   # timing begins
  400ee3:   48 89 c5                mov    %rax,%rbp
  400ee6:   8b 44 24 58             mov    0x58(%rsp),%eax
  400eea:   39 44 24 54             cmp    %eax,0x54(%rsp)
  400eee:   c6 44 24 20 00          movb   $0x0,0x20(%rsp)
  400ef3:   48 89 5c 24 28          mov    %rbx,0x28(%rsp)
  400ef8:   48 89 5c 24 30          mov    %rbx,0x30(%rsp)
  400efd:   48 c7 44 24 38 00 00    movq   $0x0,0x38(%rsp)
  400f04:   00 00 
  400f06:   c6 44 24 40 01          movb   $0x1,0x40(%rsp)
  400f0b:   0f 85 99 00 00 00       jne    400faa <main+0x22a>
  400f11:   48 8d 4c 24 1f          lea    0x1f(%rsp),%rcx
  400f16:   48 8d 54 24 20          lea    0x20(%rsp),%rdx
  400f1b:   48 8d bc 24 90 00 00    lea    0x90(%rsp),%rdi
  400f22:   00 
  400f23:   48 89 de                mov    %rbx,%rsi
  400f26:   e8 25 1a 00 00          callq  402950 <_ZN5Eigen13CwiseBinaryOpINS_8internal20scalar_difference_opIdEEKNS_12SparseMatrixIdLi0EiEEKNS_19SparseSparseProductIRS6_S8_EEEC1ES8_RSA_RKS3_>
  400f2b:   48 8d bc 24 a0 00 00    lea    0xa0(%rsp),%rdi
  400f32:   00 
  400f33:   e8 18 02 00 00          callq  401150 <_ZN5Eigen12SparseMatrixIdLi0EiED1Ev>
  400f38:   e8 43 fd ff ff          callq  400c80 <clock@plt>   # timing ends
```

I guess that in this case the compiler is not able to figure out that the result of the computation is not used, as opposed to the first two cases.

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html), then you can see that a simple operation like `+` on a sparse matrix returns not a matrix but a `CwiseUnaryOp` representing the result. I figure that if you don't use this class somewhere, then the resulting matrix is never constructed.

Answer (score 3):

I think as @hfhc2 has mentioned, the first two statements in the code get optimized away entirely by the compiler (since the results are not needed in the rest). In the third statement, an auxiliary intermediate variable is most likely produced to store the temporary result of `spIdent*spIdent`.
To see this clearly, consider the following example which includes explicit copy-assignments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main () {

   const unsigned int N = 2000000;

   SparseMatrix<double> spIdent(N,N);
   SparseMatrix<double> a(N,N), b(N,N), c(N,N);

   spIdent.reserve(N);
   spIdent.setIdentity();

   clock_t start = clock();
   a = spIdent*spIdent;
   cout << "0 Computation time: " << float(clock() - start)/1e6 << endl;

   start = clock();
   b = spIdent-spIdent;
   cout << "1 Computation time: " << float(clock() - start)/1e6 << endl;

   start = clock();
   c = a - b;
   cout << "2 Computation time: " << float(clock() - start)/1e6 << endl;

   return 0;

}
```

The measured times (without compiler optimizations) are [for openSUSE 12.2 (x86_64), g++ 4.7.1, Intel 2core 2GHz CPU]:

```
0 Computation time: 1.58737
1 Computation time: 0.417798
2 Computation time: 0.428174
```

which seems quite reasonable.